# Как статический HTML код сделать динамическим с помощью PHP?

Tags: php, html

Задача совершенно практическая. (И простите за новичковый вопрос)

Bootstrap.
Есть участок кода:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 descript-item text-center">
  <div class="circle-border">
    <a href="#descriptModal1" class="descript-link" data-toggle="modal">
      <img class="img-circle" src="img/icon/Print.png">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вызывается модальное окно:

```
<div id="descriptModal1" class="descript-modal modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <h2>Modal header</h2>
      <img src="img/1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-centered">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Таких точек вызова - несколько. Все одинаковые, только **href** разный.
Модальные окна тоже все одинаковые. Меняется несколько строк (описание, картинка...)
Проблема в том, то пока этих вызовов было штук 5, тот факт, что все окна "захардкожены" не вызывало проблем.

Но теперь, когда их стало больше, нужно, чтобы модальное окно генерировалось по конкретной информации для каждого случая.

Базы нет, есть пока текстовый файл с содержимым. И это пока устраивает.

Но, вот, с кодом что делать? Нужно его PHP менять.
К сожалению, я не знаю как это сделать...
Что подскажете?

Comment: Подскажу – вам нужен либо специалист либо курс по PHP

Answer (score 2):

Для вызова одного и того же кода с разными параметрами в программировании используются функции.

```
function getModal($header, $description, $img)
{
    ?>
    <div id="descriptModal1" class="descript-modal modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h2><?=$header?></h2>
          <img src="<?=$img?>" class="img-responsive img-centered">
          <p><?=$description?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Соответственно вызываем

```
<?php getModal("descriptModal1","img/1.jpg") ?>
```

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, как этим кодом пользоваться?

Раньше у меня вызывались модалки href'ом по id.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то при генерации окон на PHP будет использоваться один и тот же HTML-код. Следовательно необходимо проставить в HTML нужные переменные (значения, которым присваиваются непосредственно в PHP-коде) и чтобы не запутаться в окнах необходимо их как-то различать, например добавив к Id цифу

```
<?php
$header = 'Modal Header';
$description = 'Description';

for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
echo '<div id="descriptModal'.$i.'" class="descript-modal modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <h2>'.$header.'</h2>
      <img src="img/1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-centered">
      <p>'.$description.'</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Насколько я понял, этот скрипт сгенерирует html для всех нужных модалов?

И если их будет много, то html, который получит браузер, тоже будет большим?

(Это я для понимания спрашиваю)

Comment: Правильно понимаете

Comment: Спасибо, дружище!
Этот способ меня пока устраивает.